# Why doesn't forstringr::str_split_extract split on a period (.) like it will with other characters?

Tags: r, string, split

Why doesn't forstringr::str_split_extract split on a period character like it does for seemingly every other character?

Per the example from str_split_extract's manual, the following code works well:

```
code <- c("HS-IB-EDE", "OG-OYO-CAS-0121", "NY-ILR-NIG-036")

str_split_extract(code, "-", 1)

str_split_extract(code, "-", 4)
```

This returns the result:

```
> str_split_extract(code, "-", 1)
[1] "HS" "OG" "NY"
> str_split_extract(code, "-", 4)
[1] NA     "0121" "036"
```

However, if I modify this to replace "-" with "." it only returns NA for all values:

```
code <- c("HS.IB.EDE", "OG.OYO.CAS.0121", "NY.ILR.NIG.036")

str_split_extract(code, ".", 1)

str_split_extract(code, ".", 4)
```

This gives the result:

```
> str_split_extract(code, ".", 1)
[1] NA NA NA
> str_split_extract(code, ".", 4)
[1] NA NA NA
```

Why?

Example code: https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/forstringr/html/str_split_extract.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar issue with stringr:

https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/issues/303

It turns out that the pattern string is regex by default, and "." is valid regex, so it is working properly, but just not doing what I expected. So it has to be transformed into an appropriate regex expression to search for (.) using regex:

```
code <- c("HS.IB.EDE", "OG.OYO.CAS.0121", "NY.ILR.NIG.036")

str_split_extract(code, "\\.", 1)

str_split_extract(code, "\\.", 4)
```

...returns...

```
> str_split_extract(code, "\\.", 1)
[1] "HS" "OG" "NY"
> str_split_extract(code, "\\.", 4)
[1] NA     "0121" "036"
```

Comment: “and regex patterns are valid” is slightly misleading: they’re not valid, they’re *the default*. So *every* string you pass as `pattern` to `str_split_extract()` is treated as a regex. To disable this, you need to pass something other than a string, e.g. `fixed('.')`.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph, but have you got a reference? I just based this off the wording in the manual page, but you may very well be correct. https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/forstringr/html/str_split_extract.html

Comment: @LokMac that seems to be quite a niche package which is not as comprehensively documented as `stringr` which it depends on. However, the function in question uses `stringr::str_split()` under the hood where the [documentation](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_split.html) says the default is a regular expression.